# Red Triangle with an exclamation point

Tags: apt, package-management, update-manager, ppa, software-sources

I am new to Ubuntu 14.04, having just installed it 2 weeks ago. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 as my only OS. I am a new user and I have to say I love the OS but I am having a difficult time learning it. I have been adding apps from the "store" and installing software via the terminal (with a lot of help from howtos on YouTube).

I seem to have everything working well and then a red triangle with an exclamation point showed up in the tool bar on the desktop next to the two arrows for my Internet connection.

I've been reading posts but from what I see, others are getting different info than myself. I've tried `update` and `upgrade` as well as going to synaptic to reload. I'll list those results here. If you could help me figure out what is wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: this is from the package manager after reload                                                                                                                                          Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: i cant post the update/upgrade log. im being told its too long. smh,i just dont know what to do......

Comment: Remove that PPA from your sources, and then update again.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. can you tell me how exactly to do that?i have no idea how to even go about it.what is a ppa?how do i find the "source"list?is it something in the terminal?what commands are needed?i know im a totally green noob and im sorry but i need my hand held on this one.if you have the time to walk me thru it i would be thankful~

Comment: There should be a file for the PPA in question _/etc/apt/sources.list.d/_, likely called `michael-gruz-canon-trusty.list`. If you remove that file, then run `apt-get update`, you should no longer have the 404 errors for that PPA, and the triangle should go away (may need to log out and back in for that, not sure).

Comment: ok, took forever on other sites to find out what to do with "/etc/apt/sources.list".once i figured out to put it in terminal i got this message--bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: No such file or directory.doesnt make sense to me. i dont know how to pull up this "list" you all are telling me about. can you tell me how to pull up the list and then how to delete the line code when i do,please?? if i cant figure out how to pull the list i doubt ill figure out how to delete it.

Comment: Read through the [link that karel posted.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606055/red-triangle-with-an-exclamation-point/606215#comment848068_606055) It has some great answers.

Answer (score 1):

can not comment because of lack of reputation, 
but you can install Y PPA Manager & then you could remove the erroneous PPA & then try updating.

Update @Eliah, as told

To Install Y PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

as far as how to manage & other things goes: [try this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/graphical-tool-add-remove-purge-ppa/)

Comment: @EliahKagan, thanks for valuable advice. But absolute down voting will more discourage the new users rather than broadening the horizons of the site.

Comment: I have not downvoted this post. In addition to your good edits so far (expanding the post with instructions on installing Y PPA Manager), I recommend also explaining *how* to use Y PPA Manager after installing it. (I would probably *upvote* this post if it contained that information. This post's score would then be 0, or +1 if the downvoter returns to the post and chooses to undownvote. Anyway, the main reason I suggest expanding this further is not related to the voting system, but rather so that it will be more useful to the original poster here as well as others who find this by searching.)